# Why does Firebase App Distribution stall?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I have set up Firebase App Distribution following the instructions at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle

When I run `./gradlew --info assembleDevDebug appDistributionUploadDevDebug` the upload process never completes.

These are the logs from the previous command:

```
> Task :app:appDistributionUploadDevDebug
Caching disabled for task ':app:appDistributionUploadDevDebug' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':app:appDistributionUploadDevDebug' is not up-to-date because:
  Task state is not tracked.
Using APK path in the outputs directory: path/app-dev-debug.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Using service credentials file specified by the serviceCredentialsFile property in your app's build.gradle file: path/service-credentials.json
Uploading the APK.
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.39.2 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 805

curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.39.2 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$
Total: 805 bytes
grant_type=value
-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Cache-Control: private
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2022 17:16:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Total: 1,083 bytes
{"access_token":"value,"token_type":"Bearer"}
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/825351315352/apps/1:825351315352:android:4870a2ed06c3d72eb755ed/releases:upload
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: Firebase App Distro Client/null
x-goog-upload-file-name: app-dev-debug.apk
x-goog-upload-protocol: raw
x-client-version: gradle/null
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 59639628

curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'Authorization: <Not Logged>' -H 'User-Agent: Firebase App Distro Client/null' -H 'x-goog-upload-file-name: app-dev-debug.apk' -H 'x-goog-upload-protocol: raw' -H 'x-client-version: gradle/null' -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -d '@-' -- 'https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/825351315352/apps/1:825351315352:android:4870a2ed06c3d72eb755ed/releases:upload' << $$$
<============-> 98% EXECUTING [10m 22s] <============-> 98% EXECUTING [10m 23s]
> :app:appDistributionUploadDevDebug
```

when running only `./gradlew appDistributionUploadDevDebug` the process remains indefinitely at 0% with the same logs as posted above.

It stays like that indefinitely without returning errors or completing successfully. Does anyone know why that might be?